# Java - iterate through ArrayList for only increasing elements

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my ArrayList:

```
[1,2,1,0,3,4]
```

I'm trying to return this:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Here is my current attempt:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (myArray.get(i) < myArray.get(i + 1)) {
            System.out.println("Increasing sequence...");
                }
      }
```

However, this is not returning the desired output, any ideas?

Comment: Why are you keeping the 27 after the 32 (third element in your result)?

Comment: Because that 27 increases to 28 right after

Comment: I can you describe better (in words), what your code should actually do? I can't figure it out from your current example.

Comment: `a < b && a != b` is redundant.

Comment: I'm trying to iterate over an ArrayList of all numbers and return every one that is strictly increasing. I updated the arrays to a simpler example.

Comment: You have 4 lines of code here that doesn't need StackOverflow to answer. I recommend you read this post: https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/

Comment: ` this is not returning the desired output` doesn't help much. Yes, we could copy your Code and see what it does (partly, since you didn't provide much code), but it makes it harder for us. Please update your question with the current Output.

Comment: *However, this is not returning the desired output.* Your code doesn't output anything other than "Increasing sequence...". I hope you have a more serious attempt to show.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to maintain an index (or value) of the last element that you had printed and store it in some variable. Then, you'll have to use the stored element for every new element and check if is greater than the stored element.

As you have mentioned, the first element has to be anyway printed, no matter what.

Something like this might work:

```
List<Integer> myArray = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,1,0,3,4});
System.out.println(myArray.get(0));
int prevPrint = myArray.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < myArray.size();i++) {
    if (myArray.get(i) > prevPrint) {
        System.out.println(myArray.get(i));
        prevPrint = myArray.get(i);
    }
}
```

The reason why your program was failing was because you were comparing the adjacent two values only and it was possible that you might have already printed a value which is greater than any of the two adjacent values.

A similar question, but a totally different approach (LIS) exists and can be found [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/)

Comment: Thanks Parijat! This helped clarify for me.

Comment: @craz1001 were you actually looking for this only, or for a lowest common subsequence?

Answer (score 1):

A slight variant on [Parijat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47004361/3788176) to avoid repeating the `System.out.println`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.size();) {
  System.out.println(myArray.get(j));
  int start = j;
  do {
    ++j;
  while (j < myArray.size() && myArray.get(j) <= myArray.get(start));
}
```

Comment: Damn this do-while... The knowledge of do-while is so much attenuated in my mind that it feels to be almost forgotten :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static List<Integer> findIncreasingOrder(int[] nums) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int MAX = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int value = nums[i];
        if (value >MAX){
            System.out.println(value);
            MAX = value;
            result.add(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```